# Vuforia iOS Swift scene not visible

Tags: ios, swift, vuforia, image-recognition

I downloaded sample code from https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift to implement `Vuforia` with `swift`. It didn't work oob with the latest SDK, but I have successfully loaded `xml/dat` dataSet, and when I point to target method `ViewController.createStonesScene(with view: VuforiaEAGLView) -> SCNScene` is called. Unfortunately I don't see anything on camera preview. There should be a `plane` with background color, but nothing is added. Can someone help me resolve this? I wan't to display a simple plane for start. My project is at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk71oay1sopc1vp/test.zip?dl=1
Please update `Vuforia License key` in `AppDelegate`, I can't provide it as I'm not the owner of this application.

I get to the point, that I know, that scene is being displayed, but camera transformations must be wrong. Either `_cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform` or `_cameraNode.transform` (or both).

I added zNear = 0.01 to cameraNode, which was a little step. Now If I just apply `cameraNode.transform` and disable `cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform` I can see a node of correct size, but it's rotated 90 degrees, and also when I move camera it moves 90 degrees wrong (moving up/down moves it left/right). A little bit of code that does this is below:

```
- (void)setNeedsChangeSceneWithUserInfo: (NSDictionary*)userInfo {
    SCNScene* scene = [self.sceneSource sceneForEAGLView:self userInfo:userInfo];
    if (scene == nil) {
        return;
    }

    SCNCamera* camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    _cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    _cameraNode.camera = camera;
    _cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.01;
//    _cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = _projectionTransform;
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:_cameraNode];

    _renderer.scene = scene;
    _renderer.pointOfView = _cameraNode;
}

    // Set camera node matrix
- (void)setCameraMatrix:(Vuforia::Matrix44F)matrix {
    SCNMatrix4 extrinsic = [self SCNMatrix4FromVuforiaMatrix44:matrix];
    SCNMatrix4 inverted = SCNMatrix4Invert(extrinsic);
    _cameraNode.transform = inverted;
}

- (void)setProjectionMatrix:(Vuforia::Matrix44F)matrix {
    _projectionTransform = [self SCNMatrix4FromVuforiaMatrix44:matrix];
//    _cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = _projectionTransform;
}
```

So now I need to rotate whole scene 90 degrees. I think it might have been in `_cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform = _projectionTransform;`, but when I enable this, I can't see anything anymore. How to apply 90" rotation to this scene?

Here is a video of what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6pwaztlfyad8fx/ScreenRecording_09-03-2018%2015-01-17.MP4?dl=0

I think this can be in `VuforiaManager.mm`:

```
// Cache the projection matrix
const Vuforia::CameraCalibration& cameraCalibration = Vuforia::CameraDevice::getInstance().getCameraCalibration();
_projectionMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::getProjectionGL(cameraCalibration, 0.05f, 5000.0f);

[_eaglView setProjectionMatrix:_projectionMatrix];
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and update your question, showing the code that's not working - don't expect people to download, build and run your projects.

Comment: I would, but I really don't know where to look for error in this code. I described what the symptoms are, but I have no idea even in which class to look for.

Comment: Have you tried without any transform (i.e. use `SCNMatrix4Identity`)?

Comment: I did. If I disable setting both _cameraNode.transform and _cameraNode.camera.projectionTransform, then I see just a plane taking full screen, as expected. But I need to know how to transform camera to display content correctly.